# icons and some buttons of spreadjs is not working

Tags: vue.js, spreadjs

[in this image paste button,find button and some of the default buttons are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7r3u.png)

is there anything with the package that need to change, or which package is it for icons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is not the default behavior of SpreadJS's Designer Component ribbon. This sounds like an issue with how you are implementing the Designer Component.

I see here you tagged Vue.js so since this, I would recommend going through our [documentation on getting started with the Designer Component with the Vue Framework](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/designer-vue.html) and or our [Designer Component Introduction blog](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/introduction-to-the-spread-designer-component).

I also wanted to note that we also have a Vue sample that uses SpreadJS and the Designer component available in our release download link (\SpreadJS.Release.xxxx\Designer\Designer Component\samples). You can download the latest release files from [here](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/download).

If you have any other questions regarding using SpreadJS with the Designer Component, [please reach out to the SpreadJS team by submitting a ticket](https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact).